# No puedo importar paquetes correctamente Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy creando un pequeño programita en python y recien estoy en esto de el manejo de paquetes y modulos. Tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas y modulos:

```
Python
|--Test.py
|--__init__.py
Polynomial
   |--Monomial.py
   |--IncorrectGrade.py
   |--__init__.py
```

Y tengo el siguiente codigo en cada uno de los archivos:

Test.py:

```
import Polynomial.Monomial as M

m = M.Monomial(4, 2)
```

Monomial.py

```
import IncorrectGrade as IG

class Monomial:

def __init__(self, coef, grade):
    self.__coef = coef
    self.__grade = self.setGrade(grade)

def getCoef(self):
    return self.__coef

def getGrade(self):
    return self.__grade

def setCoef(self, coef):
    self.__coef = coef

def setGrade(self, grade):
    if grade >= 0:
        self.__grade = grade
    else:
        raise IG.IncorrectGrade("Grado incorrecto. El grado no puede ser negativo")

def __add__(self, other):
    if self.getGrade() == other.getGrade():
        return Monomial(self.getCoef() + other.getCoef(), self.getGrade())
    else:
        raise IG.IncorrectGrade("No se puede realizar la suma. Grados distintos")

def __sub__(self, other):
    if self.getGrade() == other.getGrade():
        return Monomial(self.getCoef() - other.getCoef(), self.getGrade())
    else:
        raise IG.IncorrectGrade("No se puede realizar la resta. Grados distintos")

def __mul__(self, other):
    return Monomial(self.getCoef() * other.getCoef(), self.getGrade() * other.getGrade())
```

IncorrectGrade.py

```
class IncorrectGrade(Exception):
     pass
```

Los archivos **__init__.py** de las dos carpetas no tienen ningun codigo.

Ahora, al trata de ejecutar el codigo desde el modulo **Test.py** me lanza el siguiente error:

```
File "/home/facundo/Documentos/Python/Test.py", line 9, in <module>
import Polynomial.Monomial as M

File "/home/facundo/Documentos/Python/Polynomial/Monomial.py", line 8, in <module>
import IncorrectGrade as IG

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IncorrectGrade'
```

Comment: ¿Donde esta el módulo `IncorrectGrade`?

Comment: Perdon, me olvide de ponerlo, esta dentro de la carpeta Polynomial

Comment: edita tu pregunta y añade todo lo necesario para que se pueda entender si deseas ayuda.

Comment: Listo, ya agregue el modulo que me faltaba.

Comment: cambia `import IncorrectGrade as IG` a  `from . import IncorrectGrade as IG`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono. Que es lo que hace el punto? Y no hay ninguna otra manera de solucionarlo sin cambiar el import?

Comment: El "." indica la misma carpeta, es una importación relativa(tambien hay ".." que es la carpeta superior), no hay otra solución desde mi punto de vista

Comment: Sí que hay otra solución que sería añadir el módulo `Polynomial` a la ruta de búsqueda de módulos (o sea, a `sys.path`). Se puede hacer de varias formas, pero no creo que sea mejor que un _import_ relativo.